# Use response url getting via ajx in ajax success not working

Tags: php, json, ajax, redirect

I am sending data from ajax and returning response from php script.

Returning response using in ajax call is not working.

I want to redirect user to url received from `**payment-process.php**` script.

**Ajax Script :**

```
<input type="submit" value="Make Payment" id="paymentbtn" class="btn btn-danger" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paymentbtn').on('click', function() {
         var customer_unique_id1 = $("#CustomerId").val();
         var customer_email1 = $("#customer_email_id").val();
         var pay_order_id1 = $("#OrderId").val();  
  
         $.ajax({
           url: 'payment-process.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {customer_unique_id: customer_unique_id1, customer_email: customer_email1, pay_order_id:payg_order_id1},
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function() {
             $('#paymentbtn').val('loading');
            },
           complete: function() {
             $('#paymentbtn').val('reset');
           },
           success: function(json) {
             if (json['error']) {
                alert(json['error']);
             }
             if (json['redirect']) {
                window.location.href = json['redirect'];
            }
          }        
      });
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Code of `payment-process.php` where getting redirect URL

```
<?php
     /// All code sending to payment gateway... and getting orderid and payment url from curl in json format....


            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url.'/create',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$arrDatajson,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            if(curl_errno($curl)){
                throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
            }
            curl_close($curl);
            $respons = json_decode($response);

                         $orderID = $respons->OrderKeyId; // Order Id created by payment gateway
                         $ppurl = $respons->PaymentProcessUrl; // Getting payment link created by payment gateway
   
           //TILL HERE WORKING AND GETTING OrderKeyId and PaymentProcessUrl...
          // Issue with following code... to send data / payment url to ajax success....

            $message = '';
           
            if(!empty($respons->OrderKeyId)){
                  $json['redirect'] = $respons->PaymentProcessUrl;                   
            }else if(!empty($respons->Message)){
                  $message =$respons->Message;
            }else{
                  $message ='Payment method credentials are Wrong..';
            }
            $json['error'] =$message;

                echo json_encode($json);

 ?>
```

I tried ajax success with response, data, html, json... but redirecting to url is not working

Comment: You should always add an `error` handler to your Ajax calls. My bet is that your server script returns an error..

Comment: @Kaddath I have added file_put_contents(".my.txt", $ppurl, FILE_APPEND); and it contains paymentprocessing url.... also added same for orderId...it is also writing orderId received...  means returning data from payment gateway is working ok..

Comment: I meant client-side, you define a `complete` and `success` functions for Ajax, but not an `error` one. It's always a good habit to have one, there can be many reasons why an Ajax call can fail, and you want to know why when it happens

Comment: @Kaddath I just tried adding error function in ajax... but not throwing any error....

Comment: My bet was wrong, as I said it's a good habit to have :P Without any other means to test your code on our side, you should open the developper tools on the page that makes the Ajax call, and go to the Network tab. Then lauch your request, you should see your ajax call in the list, and be able to see the response status and response body. Please share in the question what you see there

Answer (score 0):

There are some recommendations:

- You can check what ajax request return, also you can use `console.log(json)` to check result.
- Looks like you have typo here `pay_order_id:payg_order_id1` should be `pay_order_id:pay_order_id1`
- Ensure that your PHP script is sending the correct Content-Type header. For JSON responses, you should include `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before the echo `json_encode($json);` line in your PHP script.

Comment: Vlad Chomyl Thnx for reply... 1. console.log(json) is empty...nothins shown in console 2. that is just typomistake... 3. I added header

Comment: What is the response status? 200, 400, 500? Try also to add `$json = [];` before `$message = '';`

Comment: I also tried adding header("location: $ppurl"); before $json['redirect'] = $respons->PaymentProcessUrl; but it is also not redirecting to url...

Comment: add redirect in php is wrong, i think you just have error in php script...try to enable errors on your server or add smth like `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning. then you will be able to see some response for ajax request

Comment: @DzineTech you can't use `header("location: X");` for an ajax call, it will not redirect the client's page. I'm not sure it even can redirect the script called with Ajax to another script